# Android tablet, RFID reader module + Charging with one USBC port

Tags: charging, rfid, usb-c

I came here to ask you for some advice, comments or a completely different approach to my project.

I have an Android tablet with a USB-C port and I would like to connect to the port RFID reader module (also with USB-C), which will be glued to the tablet's back (or placed into the custom tablet foam protector), with the idea that the RFID module will be permanently occupying the USB-C port. But of course, I need to charge the tablet somehow, so I thought that I could take USB-C female and male connectors (create something like crossroad) and switch charging and RFID-reading actions via switch/button.

However, studying the datasheets for USB-C I found out that, it will not be so easy. Mainly because of the sink and source resistors, which have to be present on CC pins. It seems the thing I need is a dual-role data port, which should be capable to switch/swap roles according to the situation. Unfortunately, I was not lucky to find a detailed guide on how to construct such a connector. Basically, I understand that there has to be some mechanism, which will switch resistors/configurations from sink to source.
Can anyone please help me with some schematics/guide/video, to construct such a dual-role data port? Or if anyone has a better idea of how to add charging capability to the occupied USB-C port?

I have tried various T-splitters (the RFID module is not working after the charging plug is removed, so it is not usable) and USB-C hubs - charging is not working, because hubs were sinks.

Comment: I'm not sure how they work, but there are docking stations that allow you to charge the phone while also connecting USB devices and also powering those devices.

Answer (score -1):

i just face the same problem and here are my test results:
I connect a hub to the tablet and the power supply and the USB rfid reader to the hub.
Result:

- doing this with my mobile it worked fie.
- doing this with 1 tablet it worked also fine.
- doing this with a Lenovo tablet M10 HD it only partially worked
- connecting the power supply as the last cable connection the tablet battery loads but rfid reader does not function (though the reader gives the acoustic reading signal)
- connecting the hub cable to the tablet  last, then everything works fine.

So it looks to me, that the solution depends on the right selection of the tablet (or possibly the hub).
The problem is of course, that in real life with a fix installation the power supply may be switched off and then it won't start again.